# Save server list in steam to file

Tags: steam, counter-strike

Is there a way to back up the favorite server list in steam servers ? This gets reset most of the times during updates and its a pain to get all the servers added to this list again.

Answer (score -2):

There is a file inside your Counter-strike folder where you've installed Steam. Forgot exactly where it is. But that one contains your Favourite Servers

Comment: Actually specifying the location would make this a better answer.